# Why SharedPreferences use the context?

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, android-context

I try to use SharedPreferences, but I don't understand why we need the context.

If I create a SharedPreferences with the context of my main activity, can I get something with another context?

For example with an intentService class

Thanks

Comment: Do not ask this type of Non sense questions here. Search on _Google_

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a nonsense question.

Comment: @DerGolem I am with you.

Comment: @David Cesar Santos look at this discussion this might give you some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `IntentService` is a subclass of `Context` (just as are `Activity`, `Application`, and many other Android classes). So of course you can create a `SharedPreferences` from an `IntentService`. It will see the same `SharedPreferences` values that any `Activity` or other `Context` in your application would see. (That's why it's called *shared*.) You just have to make sure that you `apply()` or `commit()` changes made in the preference's editor in one context for the changes to be seen in other places. This is all covered in [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: Thanks for your help! With your answer I understand more about the Context and the SharedPreference. This is very help-full !

Answer (score 2):

The SharedPreferences are read and saved to disk.

Therefore the class needs to know where the app is located - and the only way to know that is thru a Context.

In standard Java there are global (static) objects, so you can do like for example System.getProperty("user.home") to access the user's home directory. That systems isnt maintained in Android - in Android you need to use the Context to get to the home dir of the app

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Android Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/app/ContextImpl.java/?v=source). You would get to know that Context class internally maintains a static HashMap of shared preferences for quick access:

```
private static final HashMap<String, SharedPreferencesImpl> sSharedPrefs =
        new HashMap<String, SharedPreferencesImpl>();
```

So you can get SharedPreferences from any class like `Intent Service` or `Activity` etc which extends `Context` and it will always return the same object if given the same name.

Note: `IntentService` does extend Context if you trace the chain:

```
IntentService extends Service
Service extends ContextWrapper
ContextWrapper extends Context
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, This is non sense question,but anyway.
As you know about SharedPreference.It is used to **Store private primitive data.**

Here,on private data term. This means this data is stored to your application's storage path. Which is `data/data/yourpackageName/shared_prefs`.

So To access your application's storage, `SharePreference` needs your active context of any running `Activity`.